# Merge two list elements into json object

Tags: c#, json, arraylist

First list:

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4]
```

Second list:

```
b=[4.233,5.2324,6.342,3.233,8.435]
```

Is there any way to merge these two lists into a json object?

Ex: object: [{"a":0,"b":4.233},{"a":1,"b":5.2324},{"a":2,"b":6.342},{"a":3,"b":3.233},{"a":4,"b":8.435}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're working server side and have two arrays `a` and `b`,

```
var a = new[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
var b = new[] {4.233, 5.2324, 6.342, 3.233, 8.435};
var c = a.Zip(b, (ai, bi) => new{a = ai, b = bi});
```

At this point, `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c)` will output the example JSON you provided. You will need [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).

[`Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___1___2__) takes the nth element of both lists, and allows you to apply a function to each combination.